# Update empty column with Data from two other columns all varchar/text Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have 2 columns named type1 & type2 in a table with the name table1 i need to populate their data to my newly created column models but not just to retrieve their data via query but to actually populate the new column "table1".models

at the moment i can have what i want with the following query

```
select concat("table1".type1,' ',"table2".type2) as models
from "table1";
```

I need an update column models command to actually populate the newly created column models in postgres.

Thank you.

Comment: `update table1 set models = concat(type1,' ',type2)`?.. is it same table, right?

Comment: Yes, i fixed it just a typo.

Comment: so you just want third column which will have `concat(type1,' ',type2)`?..

Comment: But why do you want to add this as a new column? Wouldn't that be redundant? Or can it happen voluntarily in the future to have, say, type1 = 'A', type2 = 'B', but models = 'C D'? If it's always supposed to be 'A B' then, then do't store this, but keep retrieving it from the existing columns.

Comment: Exactly Vao Tsun.

Comment: then my update statement is what you look for. But you keep same info - it feels weird

Comment: You are correct Vao Tsun. please place it as an official answer so others can see it.

Comment: @adtoctor just did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table1 set models = concat(type1,' ',type2)
```

will do what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

first alter table and add new column like this

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD type3 VARCHAR(100) NULL
```

then update table like this

```
update table1 set type3 = concat(type1,' ',type2)
```